# fetch request inside a useEffect hook only happens when the component first renders. using Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, fetch-api

When rendering the PlantTimeline component, there is a fetch request that fetches all the updates by currentPlant id. in addition there is a select input that allows to change the currentPlant. upon changing the currentPlant, i want the fetch request to happen again so that the updates will be relevant to the new currentPlant.
changing the currentPlant does render the component and triggers the useEffect, the new currentPlant is displayed, however, the fetch request does not happen more than once - when the component first renders.

noteable - i am using Redux and not useState for the currentPlant variable.

for debugging purposes i've added two console.log(...) inside of the useEffect hook:

console.log('F E T C H I N G') which logs only when the component first renders.

console.log('useEffect Happened') which logs each time i cahnge the currentPlant.

I want the fetch to also happen each time i cahnge the currentPlant.

again, i am using Redux and not useState for the currentPlant variable.

the component:

```
export default function PlantTimeline() {
    const [addPlantUpdateModal, setAddPlantUpdateModal] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const currentPlant = useAppSelector(state => state.plants.currentPlant)
    const plants = useAppSelector(state => state.plants.plants)
    const selectInput = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null)
    const [plantUpdates, setPlantUpdates] = useState<PlantUpdate[]>([])
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${BASIC_URL}/getAllUpdatesByPlantId?id=${currentPlant!.id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((updates => {
            const newUpdates = []
            for (let update of updates) {
                console.log('F E T C H I N G')
                const newUpdate = new PlantUpdate(update._id, update.plantId, update.plantName, update.dateAdded, update.img.data.data,
                                update.irrigation.boolean, update.irrigation.waterQuantity,
                                update.irrigation.fertilizer, update.irrigation.fertilizerQuantity, update.notes)
                newUpdates.push(newUpdate)
            }
            setPlantUpdates(newUpdates)
            console.log('useEffect Happened');
            
        }))
    },[currentPlant])
    function editUpdate() {
        return
    }
    function switchCurrentPlant(): void {
        const plantName = selectInput.current?.value
        for (let plant of plants) {
            if (plant.name === plantName) {
                dispatch(setCurrentPlant(plant))
                return
            }
        }
    }

    return(
        <>
        <div className="page-container">
            <div id="plant-timeline-container">
                <div className="plant-options">
                    <div id="plant-intro">
                        <img className="plant-logo" src={`data:image/png;base64,${bufferToImage(currentPlant?.imageBufferArray)}`}/>
                        <div id="current-plant-details">
                            {capitalize(currentPlant?.name as string)}<br />
                            Added on: {currentPlant?.dateAdded}<br />
                            Total Updates: {plantUpdates.length}<br />
                            Plant Id: {currentPlant?.id}
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <GreenButton text="Add an Update" onClick={() => setAddPlantUpdateModal(true)}/>
                    <div className="select-current-plant">
                        Select Current Plant<br />
                        <select defaultValue={currentPlant?.name} ref={selectInput} onChange={switchCurrentPlant}>
                            {plants.map(plant => {
                                return(
                                    <option key={plant.id}>{plant.name}</option>
                                )
                            })}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="plant-updates">
                    {plantUpdates.map((update) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="update-card" key={update.id}>
                            <div className="date-and-edit">
                                <div className="card-date">{update.dateAdded}</div>
                                <GreenButton text="Edit Update" onClick={editUpdate}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="info">
                                <div className="update-irrigation">
                                    <div className="card-property">Irrigation: {update.irrigation.IrrigationBoolean as boolean ? <img className="checked-logo" src={checkedSVG}/> : <img className="checked-logo" src={redXsvg}/>} </div>
                                    {update.irrigation.IrrigationBoolean as boolean && 
                                    <>
                                    <div className="card-property">Water Quantity: {update.irrigation.waterQuantity?.toString()} ml</div>
                                    <div className="card-property">Fertilizer: {update.irrigation.fertilizer}</div>
                                    <div className="card-property">Fertilizer Quantity: {update.irrigation.fertilizerQuantity?.toString()}</div>
                                    </>
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-property" id="update-notes">Notes: <br />{update.notes} </div>
                                <div className="update-images">
                                    <div className="card-property"><img className="update-image" src={`data:image/png;base64,${bufferToImage(update.updateImageBufferArray)}`}/> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {addPlantUpdateModal && <Modal open={addPlantUpdateModal} onClose={() => setAddPlantUpdateModal(false)} content={<AddPlantUpdateForm currentPlant={currentPlant as Plant}/>}></Modal>}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: To debug this, I suggest you move the `console.log('F E T C H I N G')` statement outside of the loop, before the `for` statement, to check if the fetch is indeed being called. If the issue persists, you could try to refactor the fetch request into a separate async function and then call it inside the `useEffect`. Let me know if you need help

Comment: Thanks for the response Stefan. I've moved the ```console.log('F E T C H I N G')``` out side of the loop and the fetch request is happening. so i guess the problem is why does it not renders the updates..

Comment: Welcome! You can try add more `console.log()` like: A `console.log(newUpdates)` statement after the `for` loop in the `fetchPlantUpdates` function to make sure the `newUpdates` array is being populated correctly or add a `console.log(plantUpdates)` statement inside your component, outside of the `useEffect`. Also check if the `plantUpdates` state is being set correctly.

Comment: I found the problem. it was with how I define ```switchCurrentPlant``` function and not with the ```useEffect``` or ``` fetch``` like I first thought. thank you Stefan.

Comment: Redux questions have as much boilerplate as redux apps.